# Use existing field as id in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Just started using elasticSearch today. I was wondering if it would be possible to set in some kind of global parameter to use a certain field within a document as the ID always?

My JSON documents will always have it's own unique ID

```
{
  "Record ID": "a06b0000004SWbdAAG",
  "System Modstamp": "01/31/2013T07:46:02.000Z",
  "body": "Test Body"
}
```

Here I would like to use Record ID as the ID field.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the path setting, see the docs here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/id-field/

specifically something like this should work in your mapping:

```
{
    "your_mapping" : {
        "_id" : {
            "path" : "Record ID"
        }
    }
}
```

I've never tried having variable names split up though. You might want to camelcase or underscore them if you run into wierdness.

Comment: When I am trying this i keep getting the error mapping type is missing.

Comment: @CoolTechie You should id at the type level and not under properties. For eg: ppings": {
        "your_mapping" : {
            "_id" : {
                "path" : "Record ID"
            },
            "properties": {
                "Record ID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },

Comment: note that it is deprecated in elasticsearch 1.5, see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6730 for more details

Comment: Is there an alternative ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to even exist anymore. The link is not there.