# Using a combined field as id mapping in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

From this question  I can see that it is possible [Use existing field as id in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653393/use-existing-field-as-id-in-elasticsearch)

My question is, if can do similar thing but concatenating fields.

```
{
"RecordID": "a06b0000004SWbdAAG",
"SystemModstamp": "01/31/2013T07:46:02.000Z",
"body": "Test Body"
}
```

And then do something like

```
{
  "your_mapping" : {
      "_id" : {
          "path" : "RecordID" + "body"
     }
 }
}
```

So the id is automatically formed from concatenating those fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, you can only make the _id point to a field that's within the document, using the dot notation as well if needed (e.g. `level1,level2.id`).

I'd suggest to have a field that contains the whole id in your documents, or even better to take the id out and provide it in the url, as configuring a path causes the document to be parsed when not needed.