# Elastic Search - Multiple Field as mapping ID in Spark

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spark-streaming

I am pretty new to elastic search. I am using `elasticsearch-hadoop 6.2.4` version and I am reading the files from `HDFS`, converting to bean object and writing to elastic search. I am using Spark Structured streaming.

```
StreamingQuery query = dataSet
                        .writeStream()
                        .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                        //.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                        .option("checkpointLocation", "\tmp\ckpt1")
                        .option("es.nodes","abc.dev.cm.par.xy.hp")
                        .option("es.port","9200")
                        .option("es.mapping.id", "CustomerID")
                        .option("es.resource", "testIndex/testType")
                        .start();
```

While writing i am giving one of the field (`CustomerID`)in the pojo class as mapping iD. Can we give multiple fields or combination of fields as mapping ID? For example, my file contains customer id as well as order id fields. Can we combine these both fields as **CustomerID+OrderID** something like that?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Skynet I tried giving multiple fields like `"es.mapping.id", "CustomerID,orderID"` and it didnt work throw me some exception.

Comment: I dont think you can substitute this with comma separated values, instead why dont you concatenate the strings before feeding them in the options - if that is feasible?

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041952/using-a-combined-field-as-id-mapping-in-elasticsearch?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @sparker, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't set multiple attributes as ***"es.mapping.id"*** . One Thing you can do is, what ever composite Id you want, Create it and append it to the Dataframe and use the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Elastic Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html/%22Elastic%20documentation%22); mapping id option is take 1 column name, so; you can not set multiple columns as id.
but you can solve this issue by creating a new column with this value like this:

```
dataSet.withColumn('id', CustomerID + OrderID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [sha2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sha2) function by generating hashed id after concatenating multiple columns.