# Custom field as id in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653393/use-existing-field-as-id-in-elasticsearch) I understood that it is deprecated.

I have data where one field is primary key. I have to load via log stash. For that, I am trying to create mapping as the way mentioned in the thread.

```
 {
  "mappings" : {
       "doc":{
         "_id" : {
           "path":"mini_system_key"
         }
        },
        "properties" : {
            "mini_system_key" : { "type" : "keyword", "index":"true", "store":"true" }
        }
    }

}
```

It throws the below error.

```
    {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [doc : {_id={path=mini_system_key}}]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [doc : {_id={path=mini_system_key}}]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [doc : {_id={path=mini_system_key}}]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

How do I achieve this? I want to have custom field as ID field?

Log stash:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/gibbs/Documents/search/mini_system_data.csv"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
               "mini_system_key"
        ]
        separator => ","
        }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["path", "host"]
  }
}
output {
    stdout
    {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
     elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "mini_system"
        document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
    }
}
```

When I try this, it is not loading the data.

It hangs as below.

./logstash -f ../config/mini_system_schema.conf

```
Sending Logstash logs to /Users/gibbs/Documents/logstash-7.6.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-05-09T20:41:47,011][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-05-09T20:41:47,124][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.6.2"}
[2020-05-09T20:41:48,846][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 36 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values 
[2020-05-09T20:41:50,657][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://127.0.0.1:9200/]}}
[2020-05-09T20:41:50,902][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://127.0.0.1:9200/"}
[2020-05-09T20:41:50,964][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-05-09T20:41:50,970][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,004][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] DEPRECATION WARNING: Connecting to an OSS distribution of Elasticsearch using the default distribution of Logstash will stop working in Logstash 8.0.0. Please upgrade to the default distribution of Elasticsearch, or use the OSS distribution of Logstash {:url=>"http://127.0.0.1:9200/"}
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,036][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//127.0.0.1:9200"]}
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,122][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,191][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Index Lifecycle Management is set to 'auto', but will be disabled - Index Lifecycle management is not installed on your Elasticsearch cluster
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,193][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been created for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,195][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2020-05-09T20:41:51,210][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/Users/gibbs/Documents/logstash-7.6.2/config/mini_system_schema.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3574edd3 run>"}
[2020-05-09T20:41:52,351][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/Users/gibbs/Documents/logstash-7.6.2/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_70546b8e568daf46c8d1fca113147a9b", :path=>["/Users/gibbs/Documents/search/mini_system_data.csv"]}
[2020-05-09T20:41:52,465][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-05-09T20:41:52,578][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2020-05-09T20:41:52,584][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-05-09T20:41:52,928][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

**EDIT:**

Data loads fine from Logstash to ES. But _id thing is not working.

Comment: It seems there is no way to accomplish this in elasticsearch. But it seems you can do it via logstash https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-create-custom-document-id-in-logstash/116629/3

Comment: There is no need to have to specify and `_id` field anymore, which is why the feature has been deprecated. Can you show your Logstash configuration file?

Comment: @Val Please check my edits. It starts Logstash. but not loading the data. I will paste the Logstash logs

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? You key column header is `key` not `mini_system_key`, so just use `key`

Comment: I solved this @Val.